# Flex4/AIR with NativeProcess: How to pass an image to the native process?

Tags: c++, apache-flex, air

I am trying to make an AIR application, that needs to pass an image (.jpg/.png) to a C++ app, that does number crunching.(this needs to be done very often, like every 2-3 seconds.) I've managed to pass the image by saving it to disk via AIR, then opening this file with the C++ program (and passing the filename as an argument to the C++ program), but this method is really slow, because it involves lots of disk I/O.

Is there a method to send an image directly to a native process?

Edit: There is a good Flash-C++ communication example at http://www.marijnspeelman.nl/blog/2008/03/06/face-detection-using-flash-and-c-revisited/ using sockets. The big problem with this method is, that some firewall settings can block the communication (i get a windows firewall warning, when i start the app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to transmit data between two processes. 
One of the most efficient, and easy to setup, is to use TCP sockets.
It means that your C/C++ will for (TCP/HTTP) requests, and that your AIR program will send the request with all data inside.

Comment: Isnt it faster to use standard input/output? And i wont run into firewall/communication problems? (for examnple one of my users has some pesky firewall software, that blocks communication)

Comment: After 2 days of messing around with standard I/O it does not seems a viable way, because its really tricky to notify the c++ process when to stop reading from the input (im far from a C++ expert). I've googled around for a TCP socket example using c++ and AIR, but could not find one.. Do you know a site which has an example?

Comment: On the Flex/AIR side, you've got to look for mx:HTTPService, it's quite easy to use.

Comment: On the C++ side, I think there's nothing in standard library, so you can either look into the socket api given by your OS, or use a cross-platform library.

Comment: I've found a pretty good socket server for my goals at http://www.marijnspeelman.nl/blog/2008/03/06/face-detection-using-flash-and-c-revisited/#comments . The only problem is, that when i start the server, it asks for Windows firewall permission. This means (i guess), that my app will be firewall settings dependent, which sucks.